# How do I pass an Array to a function? Pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Trying to teach myself how to pass an array from `int main()` to a function and I just don't understand it.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printboard( char *B ) {
 /*Purpose: to print out the tic tac toe board B
  */
    int i,j;

    printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<3;j++) {
            printf( "      %c ",B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

int main( void ) {
    char B[3][3] = { '-','-','-',
                     '-','-','-',
                     '-','-','-' };

    printboard(B);
}
```

I get this error:

```
test.c: In function 'printboard':
test.c:12: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:25: warning: passing argument 1 of 'printboard' from incompatible pointer type
```

Just need to get an understand of how pointers work and are passed so I can go ahead with my work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing multiarrays into functions through pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380196/passing-multiarrays-into-functions-through-pointer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two dimensional array decays to a pointer to one dimensional array (i.e., (*)[] )

So, change from -

```
void printboard( char *B ) 
{
   // ....
}
```

to

```
void printboard( char B[][3] )
                 // Compiler is not bothered about first index because it 
                 // converts to (*)[3]. So, is the reason it left empty.
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Also, two dimensional array initialization should be done this way -

```
char B[3][3] = { {'-','-','-'},
                 {'-','-','-'},
                 {'-','-','-'}
               };
```

[Check Results](http://ideone.com/T3clq)

Comment: @wes - The way you initialize is also correct. Because `B[][3]`, says it has 3 rows. So, with 9 elements the array should obviously have 3 columns. So, it has no problem and infact equal to `B[][3]` even while initialization. Keeping `{}` for each of the 3 elements improves redability.

Comment: Thank you - so if I'm understanding correctly, if it were a 1 dimensional array it would be *B but because its a two dimensional array, i need to point towards a "decayed" 1 dimensional array?

Comment: @Wes - If it's a 1D array, it decays to be a pointer pointing to first element of the array ( `T*`) and a 2D array decays to a pointer pointing to the 1D array ( `T (*)[]` ).